# My first many to many relationship, Declaring the model class

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

*I'm feeling a little led by MVC and Entity framework... so I need help*

The problem is I have 2 types of model: `Person`, `Sausage`

- A Person can be made without any relationships to a sausage, similarly
- a Sausage can be made without any relationships to a person.

When you go to a Person, you can add sausages he has eaten.
A sausage can be eaten by many people.

I have created 3 SQL tables:

- People
- Sausages
- Sausages_People (the relationship table which has 2 foreign keys relating to People and to Sausages tables)

I have also created 2 classes:

```
Person
Sausage
```

A Person can eat multiple sausages so I did this:

```
class Person
{
    IEnumerable<Sausage> Sausages { get; set; }
}
```

But using my entity framework DbContext, I am confused at how to link this up to the database... 
*I am creating database tables first then coding classes (migrations are off)*

```
class EFDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Sausage> Sausages { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    // I guess I need a relationship table stated here too right? so:
    public DbSet<Sausage_Person> Sausages_People { get; set; }
    // Is this right?
}
```

That means I need a separate class:

```
class Sausage_Person
{
    public int SausageID { get; set; }
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
}
```

Does that mean after all this, I actually want my Person to have a property like this:

```
class Person
{
    IEnumerable<Sausage_Person> Sausages { get; set; }
}
```

What's the usually technique for this?

When I now go to a Person and add a Sausage to him, do I just have to add a new repository method

```
AddSausagePersonRelation( int sausageID, int personID ){ ... }
```

Do I not need the IEnumerable?

Comment: Perhaps this is a bad example, but couldn't a Sausage be related to only one person, after all a sausage can be made or eaten by only one person.

Comment: Oh god i'm hungry. Depends if you like to share your sausage with others? I often find my sausage in the hands of three or four people at a time.

Answer (score 0):

you are pretty close...

but i personally would avoid the `int` constructors since  `iny,int` is ambiguous... maybe try

```
AddSausagePersonRelation( Sausage s, Person p ){ ... }
```

i would not put any `IEnumerable` in Person for the sausages...

Answer (score 0):

You do need the IEnumerable. The problem in your situation, I think, is that you are still thinking in terms of the database architecture and are including the intermediate table that links people and sausages in your object model. It is entirely unnecessary.

Let's say you are using a CodeFirst approach (I advice you to do so whenever the project makes it feasible). Then your thinking should go like this:
"Ok, so I have people and sausages. People can have 0 sausages and a sausage can be nobody's (it can be without an owner). So basically the linking infrastructure between them should be many-to-many with the possibility of no connections. What data structure do I need to represent this (it should be able to contain 0 or more references to the other class)? Well, IEnumerable/ICollection should do the trick."

Thus, you have the classes:

```
public class Person()
{
   IEnumerable<Sausage> Sausages { get; set; }

   public Person()
   {
      this.Sausages = new HashSet<Sausage>();
   }
}

public class Sausage()
{
   IEnumerable<Person> People { get; set; }

   public Person()
   {
      this.People = new HashSet<People>();
   }
}
```

If you are using CodeFirst as your approach, the table with the IDs that makes possible expressing the many-to-many relationship in terms of SQL Database design will be automatically generated by EntityFramework.

Edit:
As someone mentioned in the comments, a sausage can indeed be considered property of only one person (excluding more complicated situations like sharing, etc.). In this case, it is perfectly OK to have something like:

```
public class Person()
{
   IEnumerable<Sausage> Sausages { get; set; }

   public Person()
   {
      this.Sausages = new HashSet<Sausage>();
   }
}

public class Sausage()
{
   Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

Again, EntityFramework in case of CodeFirst will generate the tables you need in this situation. You, of course, can assume control over the exact details of that process by using [CodeFirst Data Annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx) or [FluentAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx).

Comment: I actually agree, I want to use the migrations and code first but unfortunately/...fortunately I have a SQL chappy who has pre-planned all the tables... so i'm now trying to use the existing database to set up my classes etc.. HashSet is new to me, I will study :)

Answer (score 0):

Use an ICollection so that you can add to it:

```
class Person
{
    IEnumerable<Sausage_Person> Sausages { get; set; }
}
```

Make sure to initialize it in the constructor:

```
Sausages = new HashSet<Sausage_Person> = new HashSet<Sausage_Person>();
```

To Add a Sausage to a Person you could just Add it to `Sausages` or you could write a method like this:

```
public void AddExistingSausage{Sausage sausage}
{
     var personSausage = new PersonSausage{PersonID = this.ID, SausageID = Sausage.ID};
     this.Sausages.Add(personSausage);
}
```

However, the above method depends on the `sausage` parameter being an existing `Sausage`.